# If $u, v$ have different minimal polynomials, then $F(u)$ is not isomorphic to $F(v)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Is the following true?

> Let $F$ be a field. Suppose $u,v$ have different minimal polynomials $p_u,p_v\in F[X]$, then $F(u)$ is not isomorphic to $F(v)$ as fields.

I am asking this because I noticed that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ as fields, and the proof does not seem trivial.

Comment: For your question about $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, note that any isomorphism must satisfy $2=f(\sqrt 2 \sqrt 2)=f(\sqrt 2)f(\sqrt 2)$, implying that $2=f(\sqrt 2)^2$. But then $\sqrt 2$ must have a square root in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, which you can prove it hasn't.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ have different discriminants, hence are not isomorphic as fields.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350030

Comment: Smallest counter-example: take $F=\mathbf F_2$ the field of $2$ elements, and $u=0$, $v=1$. Then $p_u=X\neq X-1=p_v$, but $\mathbf F_2(u)=\mathbf F_2=\mathbf F_2(v)$.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Speaking of that, does $\mathbb{F}_2$ mean "field with only 2 elements"? What's the difference between $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $GP(2)$? Notations in algebra are kinda hard to follow...

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf F_2$ is the field of $2$ elements. Another notation is $GF(2)$. I've never seen $GP(2)$ though.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman That was a typo :p Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2) = \Bbb Q(1+\sqrt 2)$ even if the minimal polynomial $x^2-2$ of $\sqrt 2$ is different from the minimal polynomial $x^2-2x-1$ of $1+\sqrt 2$.

The true result is: if $a$ and $b$ have the same minimal polynomial $f$ over $\Bbb Q$, then $\Bbb Q(a) \cong \Bbb Q(b)$, because they are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[X]/(f)$.

---

You are right to say that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ as fields (even if they are isomorphic as $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces, as they both have dimension $2$). The reason is simple: if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, then you could find an element $x=a+b\sqrt 3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ such that $x^2=2=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt 3$. This would imply $ab=0$ and $a^2+3b^2=2$ in the rational numbers, which is not possible.

Comment: Speaking of that, is it true that $F(u) = \{a+b\times u:a,b\in F\}$ for general field $F$ and general algebraic $u$ over $F$?

Comment: @Misakov : this is only true if $u$ has degree $2$ over $F$. In general, $F(u) = \{a_0+a_1  \cdot u + \cdots  + a_{n}u^n \mid a_i \in F, n \geq 0\}$.